# Clean up the mess of tags: [intersect], [intersection], [set-intersection], [array-intersect], [line-intersection], [intersection-observer]

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

There are many similar confusingly-named tags **'intersection/ intersect*'**, some with no tag-wiki definitions, some with self-evidently wrong definitions, all of these gloriously misused interchangeably. How many distinct use cases do we have here, and what are they?

Here are the current tags and their usage:

1) [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersection) has 1790 questions and a tag wiki suggesting it's for geometrical (2D or 3D) intersections, even though very few of its questions are about geometrical intersections, they're actually about lists, arrays, sets, collections etc.:

> *"Intersection is a term that relates to descriptive geometry and functions. Intersections are points which are included in multiple objects. They are intersections of the object they belong to."*

(also note we already have tags [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) and [computational-geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry))

2) [intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect) has 488 questions and a tag wiki suggesting it should [only be about SQL, even though it's a generic concept/keyword across many languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281433/organize-tags-for-sql-key-words). Breakdown by keyword: [SQL 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+sql), [C# 69](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+c%23), [R 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+r), [MySQL 42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+mysql), [Java 34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+java), [Linq 34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+linq), ["arrays" 31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+arrays), [sql-server 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+sql-server), [Python 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+python), [PHP 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+php), [Excel 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+excel), [JS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+javascript), [Ruby 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect+ruby) ...

> *"The SQL intersect operator returns rows that are common between two tables without returning duplicate records."*

3) [set-intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-intersection) has 196 questions: (set × 52, python × 47, c++ × 34, algorithm × 27, java × 22, list × 21, set-union × 17, arrays × 15, r × 14, intersection × 14). (Btw there's also a tag [set-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-difference), and it gets even more inconsistently used, but that's another story).

4) [array-intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-intersect) has 127 questions and the tag says it's intended only for PHP's `array_intersect()` function (should we even have a tag named after one function from one language which could easily be found from plaintext?), but still there are some other languages: python × 3, javascript × 2, c# × 2, ...

5) [line-intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line-intersection) has no tag wiki but 100 questions, across C++, C#, IOS, Google Maps, pure algorithmic, etc. What does it even mean anyway? The intersection of a line with another line? with a shape? with a volume? Parametric, non-parametric, or both?

But wait, there's more! Other hilarity-inducing tags which <s>definitely</s> arguably need a flamethrower:

6) [intersection-observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersection-observer) has 71 questions, <s>[didn't have a tag wiki until I pointed it out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54867454/revisions)</s>, and only seems to be about the Javascript API of that name (Recommendation: delete tag. Justification: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326285/creating-tags-for-a-specific-language-feature))

7) [self-intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-intersection) has 9 questions, no tag wiki, some are about 3D geometry, some 2D (maps, polygons) (Recommendation: delete tag)

8) [interval-intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interval-intersection) has 8 questions, no tag wiki, no use case (Recommendation: delete tag)

(As a footnote, how did this mess happen? Does nobody pay a blind bit of notice to tag wikis and their blatant misuse, the complete absence of a tag wiki as a signal that it might be poorly-defined/duplicate, tag synonyms...?)

Anyway, **restating the actionable questions: How many distinct use cases do we have here, and what are they?**

- assume we agree that intersection in DBs is distinct to intersection in data-structures? But then how do we name the tags?

  - [set-intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-intersection) seems sufficiently distinct and language-agnostic to warrant its own tag. Or does it. It's also currently being somewhat misused for lists, trees etc. We can't create a tag for every data-structure.
- **geometrical intersection is clearly a distinct use-case, but does it deserve a separate tag,** and if yes, shouldn't that tag be called 'geometrical-intersection' to avoid misuse? Note we already have [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) and [computational-geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry) anyway. Are 2D and 3D intersection algorithms, APIs and code sufficiently similar to cohabit in the same tag? Sometimes the result is a volume, sometimes a polygon, sometimes a line, sometimes a (discrete) set of points.

  - what do we do with [line-intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line-intersection)? Does it even have a clear definition distinct to geometrical-intersection anyway?
- It's totally asking for trouble to have two unrelated tags named [intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersect) and [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersection). Either they should be redefined and aliased, or both renamed.

Comment: `IntersectionObserver` is a Web API similar to `MutationObserver`. I don’t see why this tag should be deleted.

Comment: @Xufox: I don't know. None us of knew what it meant until [5 min ago when somebody else finally wrote a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54867454/revisions). I'm only documenting the confusion. What would you lose that plaintext search on either "IntersectionObserver" or "intersection observer" couldn't find? We cannot create a tag for every API of every language used here.

Comment: As ever with Meta, downvotes do not transmit information, so if you have a specific disagreement/improvement, please post a comment or answer.

Comment: Yes, downvotes do transmit information. They mean either, "This proposal is not well constructed or reasoned." or "I disagree with this proposal." Take your pick; either way, moderators interpret that as a sign that the retagging should not be done.

Comment: I haven't (yet) voted either way.  The tags are a mess and would benefit from a cleanup; but if we split all the intersection types up (probably a good idea) I'm not sure what to name the tags.  database-intersection and geometric-intersection seem reasonable for their categories, but I'm not thrilled by datastructure-intersection for most of the rest.

Comment: I'm a little skeptical of a geometrical intersection tag. As someone who has answered a few questions about line intersections in the image processing domain ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565975/find-intersection-point-of-two-lines-drawn-using-houghlines-opencv/46572063#46572063)), I'm mostly skeptical because the methods for doing this *wildly* vary depending on your use case, especially with the specific parameterization of your lines, e.g. Hesse normal form vs plucker coordinates vs. arrays of points.

Comment: There is a set-intersection between the intersect tags

Comment: @CodyGray: No, in this case, this post originally quickly got ~7 downvotes apparently only from 7 JS users who upvoted the comment suggesting IntersectionObserver needed its own tag (as opposed to plaintext search, which works fine for it). But now this has +34/-7 votes, so that says everyone outside that one community disagrees with them. So no, that's not a language-neutral consensus verdict on anything, and no it has nothing to do with the clarity of this proposal. Only thing we learned is that communities don't like being mentioned in an example, no matter how clearcut the misuse is.